# EF Core DB First, and how to avoid Constructor Overwrite on Model Generation

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-active-directory

I am moving away from using SQL Authentication with my Azure DB, to Active Directory Managed Authentication as explained in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi).

Basically, I'm doing two main things to get this working.

1- injecting the token in the DBContext constructor:

```
public MyDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
    var conn = (SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();
    conn.AccessToken = (new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;

}
```

2- In My Web App Startup file, I'm injecting the DBContext

```
    string SqlConnection = localConfig["SqlConnectionString"];
    services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(SqlConnection, sqlServerOptions => { sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(1000); }));
```

My problem now is that every time I need to refresh the model using the `Scaffold-DbContext` command, my `MyDbContext` gets overwritten, and I lose the changes I've done to the constructor.

What solutions are possible to avoid this problem? OR, is there a better way to inject the Token somewhere else **efficiently**?

Edit:
**Please note that I am using EF 2.x**

Answer (score 3):

I've used an interceptor to inject access tokens:

```cs
public class ManagedIdentityConnectionInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
{
    private readonly bool _useManagedIdentity;
    private readonly AzureServiceTokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public ManagedIdentityConnectionInterceptor(bool useManagedIdentity)
    {
        _useManagedIdentity = useManagedIdentity;
        _tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    }

    public override async Task<InterceptionResult> ConnectionOpeningAsync(
        DbConnection connection,
        ConnectionEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (_useManagedIdentity)
        {
            // In Azure, get an access token for the connection
            var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)connection;
            var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync(cancellationToken);
            sqlConnection.AccessToken = accessToken;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Get access token for Azure SQL DB
        var resource = "https://database.windows.net/";
        return await _tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(resource, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Which can be added like this:

```cs
// Detect environment somehow (locally you might not want to use tokens)
var useManagedIdentity = true;
var managedIdentityInterceptor = new ManagedIdentityConnectionInterceptor(useManagedIdentity);
services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString).AddInterceptors(managedIdentityInterceptor));
```

This way no changes are needed in the constructor.
The interceptor will get a token before a connection is opened to the SQL DB.
Also we avoid doing sync-over-async in the constructor.
Do note this requires EF Core 3.x.

Comment: Thank you @juunas. This looks like a very good solution. The only problem is that I'm using EF 2.x . I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Right :\ 2.2 had some version of interceptors if I recall correctly, but I didn't implement this there ever.

Comment: @AbuShokry So at the end you will come to my solution :) Which btw is the exact equivalent of your current constructor logic.

Comment: @IvanStoev How? It seems here that you are creating a new instance of the SQL connection. While my solution (as in MS docs) injects the token in the already established connection which I don't need to manage or dispose. I'm worried of hitting connection exhaustion at some point with your solution. Any references to your solution that I can read?

Comment: @AbuShokry Excerpt from the [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsextensions.usesqlserver?view=efcore-2.2#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions_UseSqlServer_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder_System_Data_Common_DbConnection_System_Action_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder__): *"If the connection is in the closed state then EF will open and close the connection as needed."*. Closing is returning the physical connection to the pool

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UseSqlServer` overload with `DbConnection` parameter and pass configured `SqlConnection` object:

```
var sqlConnectionString = localConfig["SqlConnectionString"];
services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString)
    {
        AccessToken = (new Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result
    },
    sqlServerOptions => { sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(1000); }));
```

Comment: The token expires in a few hours so that would require app restart every few hours :\

Comment: @juunas As soon as the db context is short lived (which is the usual for AspNet.Core apps), this shouldn't be a problem. But I guess your solution is better in general, just would be nice if there is something out of the box.

Comment: Your solution gets the token once at startup. It will then stop working at some point.

Comment: @juunas  Of course (shame on me)! But it wasn't intended to do so, and now doesn't :)