# Cannot Migrate DB from code with EF core and AAD authorization to SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core-migrations

**Context**

I am trying to authorize my WebApp in my SQL server. Both WebApp and SQL server are hosted on Azure.
I use Net core 3.1 and EF core 3.1. My web app is hosted on linux machine. I also have to implement feature which enable to migrate database from API endpoint.

**Repro** [tutorial I used](https://www.azurecorner.com/using-managed-service-identity-in-azure-functions-to-access-azure-sql-database/)

1. In my Web App I have API endpoint: `POST api/migrate` which is responsible for migrate my database:

```
    _dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

2. In my web app I've enabled Managed Service Identity. It could be done from Azure portal, but I have done it in ARM template for my site:

```
    "identity": {
      "type": "SystemAssigned"
    },
```

3. In my AAD I have created group (with type Security) called MSI-SQLSERVER-ACCESSGROUP. I added my web app to this group as service principal. I could do it because I'd enabled MSI before.
4. In my business database, I have added Contained user called MSI-SQLSERVER-ACCESSGROUP

```
    CREATE USER MSI-SQLSERVER-ACCESSGROUP FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER MSI-SQLSERVER-ACCESSGROUP
    ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER MSI-SQLSERVER-ACCESSGROUP
    ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER MSI-SQLSERVER-ACCESSGROUP
```

5. I add AccessToken to db connection in my dbContext constructor:

```
    var conn = (SqlConnection)_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
    conn.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
```

**Problem**

I can access database data by dbContext. Unfortunately I cannot migrate my DB. My endpoint return HTTP 500. Logs say:

> The specified schema name "{appId}@{AAD tenant id}" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

**Tried**

I have given `db_securityadmin`, `db_accessadmin`, `db_owner` to my user but it did not help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62339415/ef-core-db-first-and-how-to-avoid-constructor-overwrite-on-model-generation

Comment: How it seems to help me? It is different problem

Comment: Just to make sure you always set the `AccessToken` of the connection object. Because from the code you've posted it seems like `AccessToken` is not set when calling `Migrate`. I mean, it's unclear whether the code in bullet #5 is executed prior the `Migrate` call. If it is, then the answers from the link won`t help of course and you could ignore them along with the comment.

Comment: I set access token in DB context constructor. This problem exists only when i call dbContext.Database.Migrate(). But it works fine when I make CRUD operations